# List mysql data grouped together and show num_rows for each group

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have this SQL Code that select rows from a table and groups them together by the category column

```
echo '<strong>Categories</strong><br>';
    $sql="SELECT * from tickets where deleted = '' and DAY(datetime) = '04' and MONTH(datetime) = '".date("m")."' and YEAR(datetime) = '".date("Y")."' group by category order by datetime ASC ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        echo $result["category"].' ('.mysql_num_rows($rs).')<br>';
    }
```

when displaying the number of rows, its showing the same number on each one.

how can i make this display the correct number next to each 'category' ?

Comment: To use mysql_num_rows you'd have to do a separate select statement for each category because mysql_num_rows will always give you the total returned.  You probably want to add a count field such as count(id) to give the number of rows for each given category.  Try "SELECT count(id), * from tickets where deleted = '' and DAY(datetime) = '04' and MONTH(datetime) = '".date("m")."' and YEAR(datetime) = '".date("Y")."' group by category order by datetime ASC ";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(category) AS my_groupcount from tickets

echo $result["category"].' ('.$result["my_groupcount"].')<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do a query like this where you are using the `COUNT` function to tell you how many tickets are in each category grouping.

```
SELECT  category, COUNT(id) AS NumTickets, MIN(datetime) AS FirstDateTime
FROM tickets 
WHERE deleted = '' AND DAY(datetime) = 4 AND
        MONTH(datetime) = 12 AND YEAR(datetime) = '2012' 
GROUP BY category 
ORDER BY MIN(datetime)
```